# Are there any recorded classical Roman abbreviations of "et cetera"?

Tags: classical-latin, abbreviations

Today, there are many different abbreviations for the phrase "et cetera", including

- etc.
- &c.
- &ct.

As far as I know, the phrase was used in the classical period - in other words, it's not simply a modern-day expression. Are there any records of how Romans abbreviated "et cetera"?

Comment: You might want to read the [Wikipedia entry for ampersand (&)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ampersand), especially regarding history. Ampersand was only used in cursive, so you should not expect to find it carved in a stone.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta I didn't know that, cool. I didn't have any expectations regarding how the phrase was abbreviated, so I just gave the examples to show that there are many variants today.

Comment: I remember there was a [Tironian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tironian_notes) abbreviation for "et" that looked like 7, but I don't know the specifics about how it was used. Wikipedia says the "z" in *viz.* ("videlicet") is descended from it.

Answer (score 9):

First of all, the history of the ampersand (deriving from a ligature of a cursive *et*) is too short to be relevant to Classical Latin as @JoonasIlmavirta points out.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_classical_abbreviations) lists ZC (***z**etera et **c**etera*) or ZE (***ze**tera*) as abbreviations of *et cetera* for classical Latin.

However, as @Marc points out, the *American Society of Greek and Latin Epigraphy* doesn't list it in their common Latin abbreviations. (Apparently, their list is based on inscriptions that were published in the French publication [L'Année épigraphique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L'Ann%C3%A9e_%C3%A9pigraphique) between 1888 and 1993. The inscriptions are [available on Wikimedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Ann%C3%A9e_%C3%89pigraphique).)

I have been able to find a number of coins from the 16th century with ZC (*et cetera*) as an inscription, but of course that is not Classical Latin.

[image: ZC]

Comment: Do you have a better source than a Wiki with no sources?

Comment: https://xkcd.com/978/ -not that that is what is happening now :P

Comment: @C.M.Weimer I did find other books citing ZC and ZE as abbreviations of _et cetera_, but so far I haven't been able to find any primary source with these abbreviations. Let me dig around a little further.

Comment: I second @C.M.Weimer. It's especially concerning that neither ZC nor ZE is recorded in the [ASGLE list](http://classics.case.edu/asgle/bookshelf/abbreviations-in-latin-inscriptions/norefz/).