# Who invented the common expression "et cetera"?

Tags: classical-latin, etymology, idiom

[This question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/85/are-there-any-recorded-classical-roman-abbreviations-of-et-cetera/) seems to assume that the Romans actually used *et cetera* as we do. But did they really? By that, I mean: did they use *et cetera* at the end of a clause or phrase, without any noun agreeing with *cetera*, to mean "and so on, und so weiter, enzovoorts"?

If the Romans did not "invent" it, do we then have any idea when it began to be used in the modern way? I know it exists at least in Dutch, English, and French, but those could be borrowings from humanist Latin, for all I know.

Answer (score 1):

The Latin expression ''Et cetera'' came originally from the Ancient Greek: they came up with a few expressions like:

- ''καὶ τὰ ἕτερα''  (literally: ''and the other things'')
- ''καιὶτα τέρα'' (literally: ''and the other things'')
- ''καὶ τὰ λοιπά'' (literally: ''and the remainder'')

So the answer on your first question: no, the Romans did not invent the expression 'et cetera', but the Greeks did.

Secondly, there are many exhibits that the Romans used et cetera/et alii in speaking language. The 'et alii' is the most used form, but in the  newer Latin, et cetera became more popular. So in the time of the Roman empire, the Romans often used 'et alii', and rarely 'et cetera'. The image underneath, is from the book: *Aristophanous kōmōidiai: Comoediae in Latinum sermonem conversae (‎Christian Daniel Beck)*

[image]

As you can see, the writer used et alii, instead of et cetera.

Comment: That's very interesting. Could you show us one or more of those exhibits? It should also be noted that *et alii* as used in your example is not about "things", nor is it used substantively at the end of a sentence. An example of a Greek aequivalent in classical literature would also be useful. (I do remember seeing *ta loipa* used, but I only seem to recall seeing it used adverbally.)

Comment: There's some kind of typo in καιὶτα τέρα.

Comment: This example of *et aliī* has nothing to do with the idiomatic meaning in question, that is "and so on, und so weiter, enzovoorts". It's a plain combination of the adverb *et* "also" and the adjective *aliī* headed by *virī*, so "as many other good men do". Besides, a standalone *aliī*, being masculine, cannot refer to things - for that you need *alia*.